# Pinyin Chinese Input 20.04.3

Tags: keyboard, language-support, ibus

I've read through a number of posts on the forum and guides elsewhere, but none of them have my exact issue or offer solutions that work.

I have a fresh Ubuntu 20.04.3 installation and need to be able to write traditional Chinese characters with Pinyin. I've gone to **Settings -> Keyboard -> Input Sources** to add Chinese. Under *Chinese(Taiwan)* my options are:

- *Chinese*,
- *Chinese (CangJie3)*,
- *Chinese CangJie5)*,
- *Chinese(Chewing)*,
- *Chinese(QuickClassic)*
- *Hanyu Pinyin (with AltGr dead keys)*

of which I chose the latter. Note that there is
no "normal" Chinese option, only *Chinese (Taiwan)* and *Chinese
(Hong Kong)*. After reboot I could see the language toggle icon on
the top right, but toggling doesn't actually allow me to write
characters. Using the AltGr dead key, which my keyboard has, also
doesn't help.

Now, in many posts there is talk of a *Chinese (Intelligent Pinyin)* Input Source choice, but I lack this. All the other methods I tried, but they use different systems which I don't understand. I'm not gonna learn Zhuyin for this and wouldn't know how to with my European keyboard anyway.

The keyboard Input Method System is ibus.

I have considered trying the fctix5 way (or whatever it was called again), but as I'm new to linux and have trouble with it's console installation, I have had no success with that. How do I proceed from here? Surely I'm blatantly overlooking something.

Thank you for your patience and help!

Comment: FYI:   I assume by "*fresh Ubuntu 20.04.3 installation*", that was the media you used to install your system. Once you apply upgrades using normal commands, your system should have updated to 20.04.6, so I'll suggest you check you applied all upgrades/security-fixes. You can use the `lsb_release -a` command to view some of your system details (*other ways can be used too*); sorry I can't help with your language situation (*dumb aussie here, I struggle with just english*)

Comment: Thank you, I will check that out.